# Prove that g:R$\to$ (-1,1] defined by g(x)= cos x is surjective or not?

Tags: functions

Surjective: a function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ is called ***onto*** or surjective, if and only if every element $b \in B$ there is an element $a \in A$ with $f(a)=b$.

Really appreciate if someone explain clearly the above definition of surjectivity then I would able to prove the above statement on question.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: note that the brackets is written as above (-1,1]. in my opinion i think if the brackets written as [-1,1] then it suits the range of a cosine function which will be a surjective. this is my thought.

Comment: If we specify $(-1,1]$ as the codomain, the function is not well-defined. What is $g(\pi)$, for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your interval is $(-1, 1]$, your function is not well defined for $x= \pi$ since $cos(\pi)=-1$.

However, if you defined the interval to be $[-1, 1]$, you could conclude that the map is surjective since for any real number in $[-1, 1]$, you could find a real number,  $x \in R$ such that $cos(x)$ maps to that number.

Intuitively, think of surjectivity as being able to reach any point on the target space with your map. So if you can reach all possible points in the target space (make sure your function is well defined), the function is surjective.